# Uploading a local file to a remote hdfs with Java API but connect to localhost

Tags: java, webhdfs

I have this very simple upload method to upload a file to a one-node hdp2.5 cluster:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("webhdfs://hdsfhost:50070", conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(false, true, new Path(localFilePath), new Path(hdfsPath));
```

Tracing what happens the flow starts correctly:

- connect to hdfshost:50070,
- check if file already exists (no),
- connect to datanode.

That is where it fails: the datanode is found to be localhost:50075 instead of hdfshost:50075, resulting in a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused".

I have the following relevant settings on hdp:

- dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname => true
- dfs.datanode.http.address => 0.0.0.0:50075
- dfs.namenode.http-address => 0.0.0.0:50070

I could not find any reason why localhost is used instead of hdfshost (and there is no override in /etc/hosts, neither on the local machine neither on the cluster). Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does the machine name on the data node appear in the `/etc/hosts` file in the localhost line? If so, try moving it to the line with the actual machine's address.

Comment: Did you try to change from 0.0.0.0 to the local IP of the machine? If your machine has a static IP that doesn't change on a regular basis this could fix your problem?

Comment: @Nico I tried your suggestion, not actually believing it could help (why would it return localhost anyway?). Turns out I'm wrong and you're right, thanks! I still wonder why localhost is returned when the command hostname does return the expecting hostname, not localhost.

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons but I got this behaviour when working on load balancing with tomcat and wildfly. Since 0.0.0.0 gets resolved to localhost he will use this as the hostname while the local IP will resolve to the dns name. ( I guess )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your configuration of the http-address to your local IP address instead of 0.0.0.0. 
0.0.0.0 gets resolved to localhost and will then be used by `dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname => true` while your local IP address will be resolved to the DNS name and then be used by hostname again.

Since it works I will post this as an answer, thus I don't know if my reasoning for the solution is correct. If anybody knows the exact reason please add it as a comment or edit my answer.